# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Tags: python

Here is two vectors :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Suppose I define `Test` class this way :

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self, a, b):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
```

When I execute the command `list(map(Test, zip(a,b)))`, it says `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`. I know if I have `t = (1,2)`, then I can create an instance of `Test` with `inst = Test(*t)`. Can I apply `*` to solve my problem using `map`? Is there a workaround?

Comment: `map` yields tuples. You're looking for `itertools.starmap`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this:

```
tests = list(map(lambda args: Test(*args), zip(a,b)))
```

Which takes the `zip` values as argument to a lambda & unwraps them when calling `Test()`

This is pretty much what [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) does - so that's another option:

```
tests = list(starmap(Test, zip(a,b)))
```

The better option is to use a list-comprehension which makes the code much more readable:

```
tests = [Test(arg_a, arg_b) for (arg_a,arg_b) in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Combining list+map+lambda is a sure sign that a list comprehension is appropriate.